# Use shellscript to open url in Browser and rename tab title

Tags: bash, shell-script, firefox, chrome

I can open a url in Chrome using:

```
google-chrome "${Url}"
```

But can I also rename the tab that gets opened.

Purpose, I am opening multiple tabs, from a same website with slightly different url but all have the same default title.

Comment: Did you read the description of the command line options? Did you find any option to set the tab title? If no: Can you imagine somebody did already implement this option, but decided not to describe that in the documentation?

Comment: @Philippos I agree with you, I know there are no commandline options, but I thought somebody might have  tried something?